Unable to seed data with Docker
I'm trying to use docker-compose to spin up an ASP.NET Core Web API and a SQL Server instance, but I also want to seed my database when it starts up.
For this, I need SQL Server to be up and running so that it can create the schema, run the migration script and also seed my database.
For the seeding part I'm overriding OnModelCreating from EF Core to insert multiple records.
With my current docker-compose file, I get this error:

My docker file for my .NET backend looks like this
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 7132
EXPOSE 5194

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/MyApp/MyApp.API/MyApp.API.csproj", "Services/MyApp/MyApp.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/MyApp/MyApp.API/MyApp.API.csproj"
COPY . .


WORKDIR "/src/Services/MyApp/"

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.25
RUN /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef migrations add InitialCreate --verbose --startup-project "MyApp.API" --project "MyApp.Infrastructure"
RUN /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef database update --verbose --startup-project "MyApp.API" --project "MyApp.Infrastructure"

RUN dotnet build "MyApp.API/MyApp.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.API/MyApp.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .


ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.API.dll"]

My Docker compose file, a .NET Core and SQL Server service:
version: '3.8'

services:
  myapp-db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    container_name: myapp-db
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: mypassword
    ports:
      - "14330:1433"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - myapp-network
    volumes:
      - myapp-db-volume:/var/opt/mssql

  myapp-backend:
    build:
        context: ../myapp-backend/src
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: myapp-backend
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT: "https://+:7132"
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "http://+:7132"
    ports:
      - "7132:7132"
      - "5194:5194"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - myapp-db
    networks:
      - myapp-network

networks:
  myapp-network:

volumes:
  myapp-db-volume:

My .NET Connection string looks like this, I'm using the container name for my server:
Server=myapp-db;Database=myappdb;User Id=SA;Password=mypassword;trusted_connection=false;encrypt=false

I am using the correct user and password credentials. I did try using
I can't seem to find out why it's happening, to get around this I've been running my db container separately first, then running my backend container, and running the migration script manually.
I would like to skip having to do this and let docker do the database initialization itself.

Aside... Configure SQL Server settings with environment variables on Linux The SA_PASSWORD environment variable is deprecated. Use MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD instead.

Aside... depends_on: - myapp-db waits for the myapp-db container to start pinging, but not for the SQL Server service inside it to be running (which can take several tens of seconds on first start). Consider using a custom health script on the container that actually checks connectivity to the service inside by, e.g.: connecting and running SELECT GETDATE() successfully.

@AlwaysLearning Thanks for the heads up, i changed my ENV variable.
As for the healthcheck, I added something like this to my sql service in my compose file.
restart: unless-stopped
healthcheck:
test: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S myserverip,port -U sa -P "mypass" -Q "SELECT GETDATE()"
interval: 10s
timeout: 3s
retries: 10
start_period: 10s
It still gives me the same error for some reason.
Am i doing it wrong?
